# Numerically integrate in Matlab without requiring vector input

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

The following is  a generalisation of my problem

```
function E = FunctionIntegration(S)
    I = @(f) log(det(4 * S(f))); 
    E = integral(I, -pi, pi)
```

`S` is a function handle that takes scalar input `f` and returns a matrix. When I try and run this function I get a `Inner matrix dimensions must agree` error.

I understand that `integral` requires the function `I` to take vector input and that's where the problem lies but in this case I don't see a way of accommodating that as I must then pass this vector to function `S` which returns a matrix. Is there a way around this?

Note an example of `S` could be:

```
S = @(f) [f 0; 0 1]
```

Obviously in this case the integral is easy to do analytically but the function `S` can be any scalar to matrix transformation.

Comment: Are you trying to perform matrix integration? Or are you trying to apply `integral` element-wise? If `S` was defined (or at least a simple version was given) it would make your code runnable and clearer.

Comment: I'm not trying to perform matrix integration. The matrices are transformed to a scalar by the `det()`. I've included an example function for `S`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `integral` passes an array of values to `I`. But your `I` only expects a scalar. Try this:

```
function E = functionIntegration(S)
    I = @(x) arrayfun(@(f) log(det(4 * S(f))), x);
    E = integral(I, -pi, pi);
end
```

I've wrapped your integrand into a call to `arrayfun` which will loop over the array passed in by `integral` and calculates the integrand for each entry:

```
>> S = @(x) x * eye(3, 3);
>> functionIntegration(S)

ans =

  28.8591 + 9.8696i
```